# Parsing complex JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Guys i'm trying to parse this JSON below

```
{"response": 
{"message": "Success", 
"code": 2002, 
"payload": 
    {"article": [
                    {"timestamp_epoch": 1359967680, 
                    "search_score": 10.0, 
                    "headline": "When Sachin felt like bunking cricket practice", 
                    "timestamp": "2013-02-04 08:48:00", 
                    "related_article_count": 0, 
                    "excerpt": "...their campaign 'Support my School' by NDTV in Mumbai on Sunday. Sachin Tendulkar and Aishwarya Rai Bacchan during an event 3/5 Sachin Tendulkar and Aishwarya Rai Bacchan during an event India's Sachin Tendulkar with actress Aishwarya Rai Bachchan during the...", 
                    "source": {"name": "OneIndia", 
                                "url": "http://www.oneindia.in/", 
                                "daylife_url": "http://www.daylife.com/source/OneIndia", 
                                "rank": 3, 
                                "favicon_url": "http://favicon.daylife.com/imageserve/0e0Jd1Xczb7oW/favicon.png", 
                                "source_id": "0e0Jd1Xczb7oW", 
                                "type": "MAINSTREAM"}, 
                    "url": "http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/oneindia-cricket/~3/z1pS6w289SU/when-sachintendulkar-felt-like-bunking-cricket-practice-066016.html", 
                    "daylife_url": "http://www.daylife.com/article/07nC5eTbBE0YA", 

                    "article_id": "07nC5eTbBE0YA"}, 


                    {"timestamp_epoch": 1360361400, 
                    "search_score": 8.69279902947, 
                    "headline": "Sachin equals Sunny",
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
```

I'm just interested in **headline** and **url** values. I'm easily getting those values with this java code below.

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject response = root.getJSONObject("response");

            String attributeId = response.getString("message");
            System.out.println(attributeId);

            JSONObject payload = response.getJSONObject("payload");
            JSONArray article = payload.getJSONArray("article");



            for (int i = 0; i < article.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = article.getJSONObject(i);
                String headline = c.getString("headline");
                String url = c.getString("url");
                System.out.println(url);
                System.out.println(headline);
                strings.add(c.getString("headline").toString());
            }
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);

            resultList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here i'm setting **headline** in **ListView**(this part is working fine). And my **question** here is : when i click any list it should pass corresponding **url** to the **WebView** activity(actually I'm implementing this in another class). So how to achieve this, how to store corresponding url with headline?? please someone help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class named Article having two properties(String heading and String url).
Then generate getter/setter for both the properties. now create a ArrayList of Article type
like..

```
ArrayList<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();
```

Then while parsing your data do as..

```
Article article = new article();
```

and put value into object like..

```
article.setHeading(c.getString("headline"));
article.setUrl(c.getString("url"));
```

and add object to arraylist like..

```
articleList.add(article);
```

after all when click any list item, to hadle it add OnItemClickListener in your main activity.
it will give you position of item clicked. then you can get corresponding object's url from arcleList like..

```
articleList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            String url = articleList.get(position).getUrl();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,   WebViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

now put this url into intent in main activity and receive it into webActivity
and use it in webView finally...

Comment: Hey really nice explanation, thank you so much. But still having trouble in arrayAdapter for headline(But webView part is working fine)

Comment: ArrayAdapter problem can be solved by two ways..First-just have another arrayList say(strings) of type string as you used in your code and extract all headings from articleList and put into your strings like.. for(int i=0;i<articleList.size();i++); strings.add(articleList.get(i).getHeading()); . Now pass this list(strings) to arrayAdapter. Second you can have custom adapter, in which you have to inflate a xml having a textView and for that you can pass articleList directlly..

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Adapter which stores URL, Headline as a model and displays headline text in onView and in the onitemclicklistener of listview access the model obj inside the adapter and open webview with that URL  ... like this http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

and itemclick listener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
  Model item = (Model)contests_listView.getItemAtPosition(position);  
  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(item.getUrl()));
  startActivity(browserIntent);  // show url in browser  or pass it to your webview activity

     }
 });
```